# Is there a way to convert a string into a list?

Tags: python, list

Would there be a way to convert '[0,0,0,0,0]' back into a list?

I've tried to convert it into an integer, which didn't work. I've searched online but the articles only talk about converting strings that are like 'A BIG HOUSE' into ['A','BIG','HOUSE'].

Comment: There are several ways, depending on what you know about where the string came from. Is it a valid Python literal, or a JSON value, or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python – Convert string to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796541/python-convert-string-to-list)

Comment: @chepner It's a python literal string.

Comment: `json.loads(x)`  where x is your string - should work

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use `ast.literal_eval`

```py
import ast
my_string = '[0,0,0,0,0]' 
my_list = ast.literal_eval(my_string)
```

Comment: You should just flag this question as a duplicate.